# Power BI: Forzar la visualización de nulos en un gráfico de líneas

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

A partir de un modelo relacional de MySQL, he creado una tabla en Power Query mediante `Combinar consultas` que relaciona cada `nombre_subestilo` (parámetro de la tabla `subestilos` de MySQL) con el o los `ano` en que aparece (parámetro de la tabla `listas` de MySQL; la tabla `subestilos` se relaciona con la tabla `discos`, ésta con `canciones` y ésta finalmente con `listas`):

La tabla, que he llamado `combinada_subestilos_ano`, se ve tal que así:

```
nombre_subestilo  ano
Acoustic Rock     2005
Alternative Rock  2005
Alt-Country       2009
Alternative Dance 2009
Alternative Rock  2009
...
```

Un subestilo puede aparecer varias veces un mismo año.

Posteriormente, mediante DAX, he calculado el número de apariciones de cada subestilo por año:

```
subestilos_agrupados_por_ano = 
GROUPBY 
(
        combinada_subestilos_ano, //Tabla de partida (o expresión que devuelve una tabla)
        combinada_subestilos_ano[nombre_subestilo], //Se agrupa por subestilo
        combinada_subestilos_ano[ano], //Y por año
        "apariciones", //Nombre de la columna resultante
        COUNTX(CURRENTGROUP(), combinada_subestilos_ano[nombre_subestilo]) //Recuento: CURRENTGROUP() equivale a la tabla temporal que se está creando al agrupar; da igual usar [nombre_subestilo] o [ano] en la segunda posición
)
```

La tabla `subestilos_agrupados_por_ano` se ve tal que así:

```
nombre_subestilo  ano  apariciones
Acoustic Rock     1988 1
Acoustic Rock     1983 2
Alternative Dance 1983 7
Afrobeat          1980 1
Alternative Dance 1989 3
    ...
```

Bien, el problema es que al representar con un gráfico de líneas un subestilo cualquiera, Power BI hace una interpolación y obvia los años en que el valor debería ser 0; por ejemplo, para este caso en concreto, el subestilo no aparece ni en 1986 ni en 1987, pero Power BI los muestra como si el valor fuera 1:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado con la opción `Mostrar elementos sin datos`, tanto en `ano` como en `nombre_subestilo`, pero no funciona. La única opción es utilizar un gráfico de barras:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿De qué manera podría forzar que en un gráfico de líneas los años faltantes aparezcan con valor 0?

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir los datos de subestilos_agrupados_por_ano para tratar de replicar el grafico?

Comment: ¿La tabla entera?

Comment: Solo los datos suficientes para replicar el escenario, en los que has compartido apariciones solo tiene valor 1, ¿Qué otros valores puede tomar además de 0?

Comment: Cualquiera. Como puedes ver en la gráfica de ejemplo, "Neo Psychedelia" aparece en algunos años en 4 y 5 ocasiones.